# Vue.js pass function as prop and make child call it with data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a posts list component and a post component.

I pass a method to call from the posts list to the post component, so when a button is click it will be called.

But I want to pass the post id when this function is clicked

Code:

```js
let PostsFeed = Vue.extend({
    data: function () {
        return {
          posts: [....]
        }
    },
    template: `
      <div>
        <post v-for="post in posts" :clicked="clicked" />
      </div>
    `,
    methods: {
      clicked: function(id) {
        alert(id);
      }
    }
  }
                           
  let Post = Vue.extend({
    props: ['clicked'],
    data: function () {
        return {}
    },
    template: `
      <div>
        <button @click="clicked" />
      </div>
    `
}
```

as you can see in Post component you have a click that runs a method he got from a prop, I want to add a variable to that method.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Normally, the `click` event handler will receive the event as its first argument, but you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to tell the function what to use for its `this` and first argument(s):

```
:clicked="clicked.bind(null, post)
```

**Updated answer**: However, it might be more straightforward (and it is more Vue-standard) to have the child [emit](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#vm-emit) an event and have the parent handle it.

```js
let Post = Vue.extend({
  template: `
      <div>
        <button @click="clicked">Click me</button>
      </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      this.$emit('clicked');
    }
  }
});

let PostsFeed = Vue.extend({
  data: function() {
    return {
      posts: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  template: `
      <div>
        <post v-for="post in posts" @clicked="clicked(post)" />
      </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    clicked(id) {
      alert(id);
    }
  },
  components: {
    post: Post
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: {
    'post-feed': PostsFeed
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<post-feed></post-feed>
```

Comment: Remove 

`props: ['clicked'],`

Comment: Just a follow up on this, but it feels that this is pretty implicit behavior and would be very difficult to track what possible events could be emitted. Is there any way to declare this at the top level of the component definition?

Comment: I don't think so. Typically components are small and it is straightforward to examine the template to see what `v-on`s call what methods, and to see what methods emit what events.

Comment: Bummer - was hoping to not have to write `.stop.prevent` in all my form submit events, and create a custom form which does this once to hide the ugliness.  Passing a function as a parameter seems like the javascript way to accomplish this, but oh well.

Comment: @aaaaaa You might want to write up a question explaining what you are trying to avoid. There may be a way to do it.

Comment: @RoyJ There's no need to bind. All you have to do is this:

clicked: () => alert(id)

Comment: @Jay, https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits

You can declare all the events your component might emit if you're using Typescript...now at least.  I'm just now noting that you commented 4 years ago :D

Answer (score 3):

Using Vue 2 and expanding on @Roy J's code above, I created a method in the child component (Post) that calls the prop function and sends back a data object as part of the callback. I also passed in the post as a prop and used its ID value in the callback.

Back in the Posts component (parent), I modified the **clicked** function by referencing the event and getting the ID property that way.

Check out the working [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/12f8jopt/17/)

And this is the code:

```
let Post = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    onClicked: Function,
    post: Object
  },
  template: `
      <div>
        <button @click="clicked">Click me</button>
      </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    clicked() {
        this.onClicked({
        id: this.post.id
      });
    }
  }
});

let PostsFeed = Vue.extend({
  data: function() {
    return {
      posts: [
        {id: 1, title: 'Roadtrip', content: 'Awesome content goes here'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Cool post', content: 'Awesome content goes here'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Motorcycle', content: 'Awesome content goes here'},
      ]
    }
  },
  template: `
      <div>
        <post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :onClicked="clicked" />
      </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    clicked(event) {
      alert(event.id);
    }
  },
  components: {
    post: Post
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'post-feed': PostsFeed
  }
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <post-feed></post-feed>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the service:

```
export const getBuilding = () => {
  console.log("service");
  return 0;
};
```

in the parent component:

```
<Update-Theme :method="parentMethod"/>

import { getBuilding } from "./service";
methods: {
    parentMethod() {
      console.log("Parent");
      getBuilding();
    },
}
```

and in the child component

```
<v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="closeDialog()">
props: [ "method"],
 methods: {
    closeDialog() {
      this.method();
      //this.$emit("update:dialog", false);
    },
}
```